# Creating a single boot CD from multiple boot ISOs

Tags: boot, iso-image

I have two different boot ISO images which I need to burn onto a single CD. The goal is that when I boot from the CD it should ask me which image to boot from first.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: I heard this task is possible in Magic ISO.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got my exact need in Magic ISO. This tool has that functionality like making multi boot ISO

[Refer It](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-createmultibootcd.htm)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to use DAEMON(you can download it free) Tool to read your ISOs , then copy files of the both iso in the same folder of your local hard drive and finally using NERO Tool you can create a single ISO.

I hope that this could help you.

Best Regards,

Comment: what about boot menu? My aim was not to merge ISO's